# Weird shadowy diagonal lines along edge of mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, maya

First, here's an example of what I am describing as "Weird shadowy diagonal lines".

[image: Example of shadowy lines]

This is the top of a table constructed in Maya an exported as `.obj`. It is loaded as follows:

```
let mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtlLoader.setPath( './assets/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'table.mtl', ( materials ) => {

    materials.preload();

    let objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( './assets/' );
    objLoader.load( 'table.obj', ( object ) => {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            let _color = child.material.color;
            if ( _color.r === 0 && _color.g === 0 && _color.b === 0 ) {
                child.material.color.r = 0.65;
                child.material.color.g = 0.65;
                child.material.color.b = 0.65;
            }
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;
            child.material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
        }

        scene.add( object );
        animate();
    }
}
```

There is only one light in this scene and here is the code that produces it.

```
SpotLight_1 = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
SpotLight_1.position.set( 60, 90, 60 );
SpotLight_1.castShadow = true;
SpotLight_1.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
SpotLight_1.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
scene.add( this.three.SpotLight_1 );
```

Here is the part that will probably make the problem apparent to someone with more experience with 3d meshes and three js than myself... If I set the `SpotLight_1.shadow.mapSize.width = 128` set the `mapSize.height` equal to 128 as well, the lines span the whole inner surface of the table. Here is a picture.

[image: Example of lines spanning inner mesh]

The inner mesh material type is phong, the border is lambert if this is pertinent.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the angle of the light hitting a reflective surface. The light is @ 60 on Y-axis and the table has a collective height of 30.5. The affect is noticeable when the camera is rotated such that the table is between the light and the camera.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. If any additional information is needed I will be happy to provide.

Comment: Ok so I fixed this in this situation by making it so that the top of the table does not receive shadows. That works considering nothing is displayed on the table. I would still like to know what is causing this so that I can avoid it in situations that do require shadows on the surface.

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with an issue related to the geometry or your lighting setup and/or render settings in the maya scene than an issue with your code... For example, I see a lot of anti-aliasing issues in your render, so there must be some additional settings you need to tweak.

Comment: We can't be 100% sure without a complete scene setup (running code sample), but to me this just looks like *shadow acne*, a common problem with current shadow mapping techniques. Once you know what it's called, it's much easier to find information on :).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will dig into them and either edit my question, or provide more feedback!